# How to format excel cells using pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Can you "format cell" using pandas?

I have a column that has large numbers so excel auto the numbers as exponents. I want it so the decimal place will be "0" for the column so I can have a whole number.

Ex. On excel

```
     A
27782239216
3.93479E+11<---
97336460903
6.40211E+12<---
5.58299E+12<---
```

I want to set the decimal place in column A to be 0

Ex. On excel

```
     A
27782239216
393479119893<---
97336460903
6402108304702<---
5582993267823<---
```

Is there a `add format` function for pandas I can use?

Comment: no there isn't.  You could see if setting the column to integer in pandas made any difference when saving to excel and loading.

Answer (score 0):

use below numpy code if there arre integers only:

```
import numpy as np
dataFrame['ColumnName'] = dataFrame['ColumnName'].astype(np.int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could change display format like below

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:20,.2f}'.format
```

or

```
df['A'].apply(lambda x: '%.1f' % x)
```

Comment: If i save my xlsx file using this code will it show whole numbers?

Comment: @JohnZapanta use df['A'].apply(lambda x: '%.1f' % x) this line yes it will show whole number